# windows 10 add remove programs missing version info

Tags: windows-10

I'm a developer who is responsible for, among other things, the installer (and InstallScript project) for our product. We have 10 or so dependencies that sometimes cause issues for us. Our usual first stop when troubleshooting is Add/Remove Programs to see what is installed. On Win 7, the Version of a component is listed alongside the name of the installed packages. However, on Win 10, the version is missing. This is highly problematic when there are three Visual C++ 20xx Redistributables listed, but we can't easily see what the versions they are.

Has anyone else noticed this? Found a way to turn that info on with a tweak somehow? I can get the info from 'wmic', but that's a hard sell when I'm dealing with a customer on the phone.

Comment: Well, if you don't like that tell it to Microsoft. One way is to participate in Insider Preview program. If many people ask for it, then there are chance it will come back.

Comment: By the way, the old control panel still has that information.

Comment: @Phil1970 - I was unaware that the old CP was still available. That does indeed give me what I need. Thanks!